# Windows 10 exe file's imagebase doesn't change

Tags: windows, aslr

I am a student who studies reverse engineering. After I studied ASLR on Windows, I was going to check it. following capture:
[image: loading notepad.exe on Windows 10 1st and 2nd time]

[image]

the image base of notepad are same on first and second time. Whenever I restart notepad on ollydbg, imagebase is same. I checked ASLR attributes on file via PEView and registry value on Windows 10 too. they are normal. is there any reason not be changed imagebase of notepad ?

Answer (score 1):

Base address will change on PC's restart. It will not change on app's restart.

[Writing Secure Code for Windows Vista by Michael Howard - Senior Security Program Manager at Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_howard/2006/05/26/address-space-layout-randomization-in-windows-vista/)