# Why I don't see address layout randomization in debugger?

Tags: assembly, memory, virtual-memory, aslr

When I'm looking at my assembly in debugger on (MSVS 2019) I don't see any address randomization. It doesn't matter how many times I stop and start again. (Shift+f5 to stop, f11 to start again) .text segment addresses staying the same.

I guess debugger trying to help me, and disable /DYNAMICBASE key.

My question is, how can I see with my own eyes that ASLR is working? VMMap say that ASLR is woring, but I still the same virtual memory offset as in debugger.

Dumpbin /headers:
(My code isn't DLL, it's just the only thing that seems pertinent in output)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 exe file's imagebase doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623369/windows-10-exe-files-imagebase-doesnt-change)

Comment: Most debuggers disable ASLR.  GDB does that even on Linux where stack and image-base address *does* change on every run of the program.  GDB has an option to not disable ASLR; look for the same in your Windows debugger.

Comment: Run the program normally (run from explorer or command line), _then_ attach the debugger after Windows has started the program.

Comment: @RaymondChen: is that true that Windows only re-randomizes program addresses on reboot like the answer on that other question claims?  Not on re-running the program.  That answer doesn't have any upvotes, so IDK how you were able to select it as a duplicate target. (Maybe someone removed their upvote after that?)

Comment: The general rule is that if a module is already loaded, then ASLR will reload it at the same address in order to permit code page sharing. (Linux solves this problem by requiring PIC. Windows does not require PIC.) There may be some cache effects (because the code pages are still in cache even if no process is using the module), but you can guarantee a new address with a reboot.

Comment: Plus, would it randomize if loaded through a debugger? I would add some debug code that printed out that address of some function at application start up and see if that changed rather than rely on the debugger.

Comment: The more I think about this, it would be absurd for a debugger to load a program and randomize memory. Think about what that would do to break and watch points.